# How do symbols solve walking the stack with FPO in x86 debugging?

Tags: windows, debugging, x86, symbols, callstack

In this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8646611/192359 , it is explained that when debugging x86 code, symbols allow the debugger to display the callstack even when FPO (Frame Pointer Omission) is used.

The given explanation is:

> On the x86 PDBs contain FPO information, which allows the debugger to reliably unwind a call stack.

My question is what's this information? As far as I understand, just knowing whether a function has FPO or not does not help you finding the original value of the stack pointer, since that depends on runtime information.

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679352(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: IDK what Windows does, but the Linux (System V ABI) equivalent stack-unwind info (`.eh_frame`) records which instruction addresses push which call-preserved register, so there's enough info to unwind the stack and restore registers.  Presumably that's the kind of FPO information that the Windows ABI uses, too.  (You can have that with or without other debug info that maps symbols to var names.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally, it is always possible to walk the stack with enough information<sup>1</sup>, except in cases where the stack or execution context has been irrecoverably corrupted.

For example, even if `rbp` isn't used as the frame pointer, the return address is still on the stack somewhere, and you just need to know where. For a function that doesn't modify `rsp` (indirectly or directly) in the body of the function it would be at a simple fixed offset from `rsp`. For functions that modify `rsp` in the body of the function (i.e., that have a variable stack size), the offset from `rsp` might depend on the exact location in the function.

The PDB file simply contains this "side band" information which allows someone to determine the return address for any instruction in the function. Hans linked a relevant in-memory structure [above](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679352(v=vs.85).aspx) - you can see that since it knows the size of the local variables and so on it can calculate the offset between `rsp` and the base of the frame, and hence get at the return address. It also knows how many instruction bytes are part of the "prolog" which is important because if the IP is still in that region, different rules apply (i.e., the stack hasn't been adjusted to reflect the locals in this function yet).

In 64-bit Windows, the exact function call ABI has been made a bit more concrete, and *all* functions generally have to provide unwind information: not in a `.pdb` but directly in a section included in the binary. So even without `.pdb` files you should be able to unwind a properly structured 64-bit Windows program. It allows *any* register to be used as the frame pointer, and still allows frame-pointer omission (with some restrictions). For details, [start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tawsa7cb.aspx).

---

<sup>1</sup> If this weren't true, ask yourself how the currently running function could ever return? Now, *technically* you could design a program which clobbers or forgets the stack in a way that it cannot return, and either never exits or uses a method like `exit()` or `abort()` to terminate. This is highly unusual and not possibly outside of assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So to see that I understand correctly - there can't be conditional stack pointer changes (no push/pop/'sub esp' in an if clause)? meaning that for each position in the function I can know the current offset from the original stack pointer?

Comment: Yes, there can be conditional/variable changes to the stack (the prime suspects are `alloca` and VLAs) but in that case the compiler will generally use a frame pointer, since that's a fast way to remember the base of the stack (which is needed to return from the function). So you can easily walk such functions as well (the .pdb and/or PROC_FRAME section includes information about which register is used as the frame pointer in this case). @asaf